# How do I display multiple stacked columns for each date range in an stacked Bar

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, week-number

Essentially, the purpose is to compare what categories of tasks each member on my team is performing on a weekly basis.

and I would like to add number of Week underneath the Axes instead of 1.0 , 2.0 and 3.0 .

I am getting wrong result as its only showing 1 for excellent and for all week1, week2, week3, week4

I selected starting day 1/12/2014 and the end date is 31/12/2014 so I was expecting to have 1 for bad and two for good and three for excellent.

[image]

This is my PHP code

```
<?php>
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `employees` WHERE  `Date` BETWEEN  '" . $_POST     
['start'] . "' AND  '" . $_POST ['end'] . "' ") or die ("Error: ".mysqli_error($con));

$Levels = 0;
        $Levelscounter=0;
        $countergood=0;
        $counterbad=0;
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
         {
            $answer = $row['level'];


                 $bad = 'bad';
                 $good='good';
                 $excellent='excellent';
                  if ($answer == $bad)

             {
                $counterbad++;
             }
             if($answer == $good)
             {
               $countergood++;
             }
             if($answer == $excellent)
             {
               $counterexcellent++;
             }
             $Levelscounter;
                        }
             mysqli_close($con); 
        ?>
```

Here is my JavaScript Code:

```
       <script type="text/javascript">
         (function($) {
          var series = [{
          data: [[ 1,<?php echo $counterbad; ?>] ],
               valueLabels: {
               show: true,
               valign: 'middle'
                }     ,
         label: "Low"
         },
         {
       data: [[1,<?php echo $countergood; ?>]], 
           valueLabels: {
    show: true,
    valign: 'middle'
}     ,

    label: "Medium"
   }, {
    data: [[1,<?php echo $counterexcellent; ?>]],
     valueLabels: {
    show: true,
    valign: 'middle'
   }     ,
    label: "High"
   }];

    var options = {
    xaxis: {
        minTickSize: 1
    },
    series: {
        bars: {
            show: true,
            barWidth: .8,
            align: "center"
        },
        stack: true
    }
   };

  $.plot("#placeholder", series, options);
  })(jQuery);
 </script>
```

I got the levels displayed in the stacked chart and it is working fine regarding from the start and end date I select but I could display this result as a weekly result.
I would like to get ideas what do I need to add ? Any ideas please ?
Is there a function in PHP that sort out this ?

Thank you.

Updating

As you can see in the image numbers on each series related to bad, good, excellent.
red for bad and good for blue and yellow for excellent.
[image]

Comment: What jquery library are you using for the charts and do you want to display the data for the last 3 weeks ? Week 1, Week 2, Week 3 for example

Comment: @CodingInsane I would like to display week1, week2, week3, week4 underneath the x axis and each week would have a stacked bar .Here are the libraryjquery.flot.stack.js jquery.flot.valuelabels.js jquery.flot.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add [weeks/textual](http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/categories/index.html) data underneath the columns you have to add the library's categories file `jquery.flot.categories.min.js` to your javascript assets.

If i understand you correctly you want the chart to look like this

[image]

### Javascript

You need to add these files in

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.flot.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.flot.categories.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.flot.stack.min.js"></script>
```

and initialize the library we will talk about `$output` after this code

```
<div id="placeholder" style="width:818px;height:413px" ></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    var series = [<?php echo $output; ?>];
       $.plot("#placeholder", series, {
        series: {
            stack:true,
            lines:{fill:true,show:false,steps:false},
            bars: {
                show: true,
                barWidth: 0.8,
                align: "middle",
            },
        },
        xaxis: {
            mode: "categories",
            minTickSize: 1
        }
       });
});
```

### PHP

First you need to query the database to find the date between the specified dates, after getting the result you have to sort the data for each week in an array

For instance `week One => 'good','good','bad','bad', 'week two' => and so on ...`

after that you can use [`array_count_values()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) to count the number of occurrences and build
the charts column.

I simplified the code using  `functions` to make it easier for you

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", 'root','','your db');

function getChartData($con, $startDate, $endDate){

    $startDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($startDate));
    $endDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($endDate));

    $query = "SELECT * FROM `employees` WHERE `date` BETWEEN '$startDate' AND '$endDate'";

    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die ("Error: ".mysqli_error($con));

    // a multidimenional array containing each week with it's
    $weeksData = [];

    // Group each week with it's data 
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        $weekNumber = date("W", strtotime($row['date']));
        if(isset($weeksData[$weekNumber]))
        {
            $weeksData[$weekNumber][] = $row['level'];
        }
        $weeksData[$weekNumber][] = $row['level'];
    }

    // reset array indexes and sort the array
    sort($weeksData);

    $data = array();

    // using array_count_values to count the number of (good, bad and excellent)
    foreach ($weeksData as $key => $week) {
        $data[$key] = array_count_values($week);
    }

    // return all the weeks with number of (good, bad and excellent) occurences 
    return $data;
}

// build the javascript object {data:['week num', occuerences]}
function buildColumn($data,$label, $numberOfWeeks)
{
    $data = array_column($data,strtolower($label));
    $balance = $numberOfWeeks - count($data);
    if($balance !=0){ 
        for($i=1;$i<=$balance;$i++) { 
            $data[] = 1; 
        } 
    }

    $string = '{data: [';
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        $weekNumber = $key+1;
        $string .= '["Week '.$weekNumber.'",'.$value.'],';
    }
    $string = rtrim($string, ',');
    $string .= "],valueLabels: {show: true,valign: 'middle'},label: '$label'}";
    return $string;
}

function getNumberofWeeks($startDate, $endDate){
      $weeks = array();
      $period = new DatePeriod(new DateTime($startDate),
        DateInterval::createFromDateString('+1 day'),new DateTime($endDate) 
      );
      foreach ( $period as $dt ) {
        $weeks[] = $dt->format( 'W' );
      }
      return count(array_unique($weeks));
}
```

now you can easily use these functions like this

```
$numberOfWeeks = getNumberofWeeks($_POST['start'],$_POST['end']);

// get data of the last number of weeks
$chartData = getChartData($con, $_POST['start'],$_POST['end']);
// bulding columns data for each occurence
$badColumn = buildColumn($chartData,'Bad', $numberOfWeeks);
$goodColumn = buildColumn($chartData,'Good', $numberOfWeeks);
$excellentColumn = buildColumn($chartData,'Excellent', $numberOfWeeks);

// output {data: ...}, {data: ...},{data:....}
$output = "$excellentColumn , $goodColumn , $badColumn";
```

### Full working Example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.flot.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.flot.categories.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.flot.stack.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", 'root','','your db');

function getChartData($con, $startDate, $endDate){

    $startDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($startDate));
    $endDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($endDate));

    $query = "SELECT * FROM `employees` WHERE `date` BETWEEN '$startDate' AND '$endDate'";

    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die ("Error: ".mysqli_error($con));

    // a multidimenional array containing each week with it's
    $weeksData = [];

    // Group each week with it's data 
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        $weekNumber = date("W", strtotime($row['date']));
        if(isset($weeksData[$weekNumber]))
        {
            $weeksData[$weekNumber][] = $row['level'];
        }
        $weeksData[$weekNumber][] = $row['level'];
    }

    // reset array indexes and sort the array
    sort($weeksData);

    $data = array();

    // using array_count_values to count the number of (good, bad and excellent)
    foreach ($weeksData as $key => $week) {
        $data[$key] = array_count_values($week);
    }

    // return all the weeks with number of (good, bad and excellent) occurences 
    return $data;
}

// build the javascript object {data:['week num', occuerences]}
function buildColumn($data,$label, $numberOfWeeks)
{
    $data = array_column($data,strtolower($label));
    $balance = $numberOfWeeks - count($data);
    if($balance !=0){ 
        for($i=1;$i<=$balance;$i++) { 
            $data[] = 1; 
        } 
    }

    $string = '{data: [';
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        $weekNumber = $key+1;
        $string .= '["Week '.$weekNumber.'",'.$value.'],';
    }
    $string = rtrim($string, ',');
    $string .= "],valueLabels: {show: true,valign: 'middle'},label: '$label'}";
    return $string;
}

function getNumberofWeeks($startDate, $endDate){
      $weeks = array();
      $period = new DatePeriod(new DateTime($startDate),
        DateInterval::createFromDateString('+1 day'),new DateTime($endDate) 
      );
      foreach ( $period as $dt ) {
        $weeks[] = $dt->format( 'W' );
      }
      return count(array_unique($weeks));
}
// the number of weeks that you want to display in the chart
$numberOfWeeks = getNumberofWeeks($_POST['start'],$_POST['end']);

// get data of the last number of weeks
$chartData = getChartData($con, $_POST['start'],$_POST['end']);
// bulding columns data for each occurence
$badColumn = buildColumn($chartData,'Bad', $numberOfWeeks);
$goodColumn = buildColumn($chartData,'Good', $numberOfWeeks);
$excellentColumn = buildColumn($chartData,'Excellent', $numberOfWeeks);

// output {data: ...}, {data: ...},{data:....}
$output = "$excellentColumn , $goodColumn , $badColumn";

?>
<div id="placeholder" style="width:818px;height:413px" ></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    var series = [<?php echo $output; ?>];
       $.plot("#placeholder", series, {
        series: {
            stack:true,
            lines:{fill:true,show:false,steps:false},
            bars: {
                show: true,
                barWidth: 0.8,
                align: "middle",
            },
        },
        xaxis: {
            mode: "categories",
            minTickSize: 1
        }
       });
});
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

### Edit

Just replace these two functions to make it compatible with `dd/mm/yyyy`

```
 function getChartData($con, $startDate, $endDate){
    $startDate = explode('/', $startDate);
    $startDate = $startDate[1] . '/' . $startDate[0] . '/' . $startDate[2];

    $endDate = explode('/', $endDate);
    $endDate = $endDate[1] . '/' . $endDate[0] . '/' . $endDate[2];

    $startDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($startDate));
    $endDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($endDate));

    $query = "SELECT * FROM `employees` WHERE `date` BETWEEN '$startDate' AND '$endDate'";

    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die ("Error: ".mysqli_error($con));

    // a multidimenional array containing each week with it's
    $weeksData = [];

    // Group each week with it's data 
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        $weekNumber = date("W", strtotime($row['date']));
        if(isset($weeksData[$weekNumber]))
        {
            $weeksData[$weekNumber][] = $row['level'];
        }
        $weeksData[$weekNumber][] = $row['level'];
    }

    // reset array indexes and sort the array
    sort($weeksData);

    $data = array();

    // using array_count_values to count the number of (good, bad and excellent)
    foreach ($weeksData as $key => $week) {
        $data[$key] = array_count_values($week);
    }

    // return all the weeks with number of (good, bad and excellent) occurences 
    return $data;
}
```

and

```
   function getNumberofWeeks($startDate, $endDate){
    $startDate = explode('/', $startDate);
    $startDate = $startDate[1] . '/' . $startDate[0] . '/' . $startDate[2];

    $endDate = explode('/', $endDate);
    $endDate = $endDate[1] . '/' . $endDate[0] . '/' . $endDate[2];
    $diff = strtotime($startDate, 0) - strtotime($endDate, 0);

    return str_replace('-','', (int)floor($diff / 604800));
}
```

Comment: @Codinglnsane I have correct code but I don't know how to build it up no ideas

Comment: @ZinaDweeikat i will edit my answer just small changes and it will work with your $_POST start and end, ofcourse your code is correct for showing one column. but you have to get the number of weeks between two dates and group those weeks with their occurrences then display the data for each week. this is for sure more complicated than your one column code.

Comment: did you copy the javascript as shown on the answer ? if copy it and try it. and what php version are using ? make sure error reporting is enabled. and in what format are you posting the date ? mm/dd/yyyy or dd/mm/yyyy give me the exact format to make sure that php is handling it correctly

Comment: yes i got the problem i tested the code with mm/dd/yyyy that's why it's not working i will change the format in my code to dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: @ZinaDweeikat see Edit section in my answer just replace `getChartData()` and `getNumereoWeeks` and everything should be fine